# NullPointerException when i want to display data in the log

Tags: java, android, android-layout, static-methods

Below is the data class that I am using

**Data Class**

```
public class Data {       
        private static String product;
        public static String getData() {
            return product;


}

    public static void setData(String data) {
        product = data;
        Log.d("Data", product.toString()); 
    }
}
```

I am getting the object in the below Fragment class:

**Fragment Class**

```
public class contact_details_tab extends Fragment {
     TextView hostel_name;
     JSONObject product;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_details_tab, container, false);
        hostel_name = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hostel_name);

        product = Data.getData();

        try {
            hostel_name.setText(product.getString("h_name"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("Data", e.getMessage());
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

When I try to print the data in the log I always get the error `"println needs a message"`

Comment: `product =Data.getData();` How does this compile? `getData` returns a `String` and product is a `JSONObject`.

Comment: thanks  user2336315 i solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the Log methods in the recommended way, which can lead to this failure of the println() mechanism used in their implementation when the null argument passed to the Log method gets passed through to println().

Normally, the first argument, or *TAG* should indicate the name of the component doing the logging, for example the name of your Activity.

The second argument should consist of a String explaining what you are logging, followed by the value itself.

The sound practice is to first declare your TAG for the component near the start of your Class:

```
private static final String TAG = "DataClass";
```

And then log your messages with explanation

```
  Log.d(TAG, "Set data to " + product);
```

This way, even if `product` is null it will just be appending that to a String, which is a legitimate operation producing informative output.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding `+""` when ever I call the log

Comment: Actually this proposes a distinct dolution - one that is probably unreliable.  I had suggested appending the unknown to a constsnt string, not the reverse shown here.